# NUGet Package oddities

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I need access to the Azure Graph API and have implemented it using the Graph Client library, which is a nuget packages. But now I run into weird issues with that package in nuget.

I have done the following:

- Via Nuget Package manager, I added `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.dll` in version 2.1.1 to the project.
- I then looked into the packages folder and found that `packages\Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.2.1.1\lib\portable-net4+sl5+win+wpa+wp8\Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.dll` is 716,752 bytes and has version 1.0.9342.13, changed Sep 15th, 2016.

So, the version number is really really off. I removed the version from the solution and made sure there are no leftovers in the packages folder. Then,

- Via Nuget Package manager, I added `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.dll` in version 2.1.0 to the project.
- I then looked into the packages folder and found that `packages\Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.2.1.0\lib\portable-net4+sl5+win+wpa+wp8\Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.dll` is 558,824 bytes and has version 2.1.1.0, changed Mar 3rd, 2016.

Can someone please elaborate whether I am doing something wrong, or whether this is an issue of nuget. What is the most recent version of said library, and where and how do I reliably get it?

Comment: The NuGet package version doesn't have to correlate to the contained assembly's version. So this looks like an XY problem, what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with CodeCaster. NuGet deals with Packages rather than assemblies. Those packages in turn can bring in zero or more assemblies. The assembly versions may or may not match the package version, though in most cases they do.

Please refer to:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/nuget-versioning-part-2-core-algorithm.html